# Android string manipulation

Tags: java, regex, string

For this string, `16.82080560, 96.13055810` I want to get

```
"String one = 16.82080560"
```

and

```
"String two = 96.13055810"
```

in android.
Admin that I suck in string manipulation and regex.
Please let me know how can I get such two value from a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
String str = "16.82080560, 96.13055810";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,", ");
String one = st.nextToken();
String two = st.nextToken();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
String[] components = original.split(",");
```

If the Strings  are always separated by a comma you can use `String.split`

For a better regex pattern see the comment from `@npinti`:

> Minor side note, it might be better to do \\s*,\\s* instead of just ,.
>   Just , might cause problems should the OP wish to cast these to
>   floats, since the extra white space at the beginning of the second
>   number will most likely not be recognized as a proper number.

Comment: Beat me to it. This one gives you `components[0] = 16.82080560` and `components[1] = 96.13055810 `

Comment: Minor side note, it might be better to do `\\s*,\\s*` instead of just `,`. Just `,` might cause problems should the OP wish to cast these to floats, since the extra white space at the beginning of the second number will most likely not be recognized as a proper number.

Comment: @npinti thanks. I will edit the answer? Could be trim() a workaround?

Comment: @blackbelt Yes that is valid, however, I think that you will have to either iterate over the string array once more and overwrite the value with the trimmed one, or else, call `.trim()` each and every time.

Comment: @blackbelt I've tried like that already. Cannot get though because of space.

Comment: @ppshein: Did you try it like so: `String[] components = original.split("\\s*,\\s*);`. This should remove the comma and the surrounding whitespaces, if any.